# high res/retina full size backgrounds

Tags: css, background-image

How do you add a retina background if you want the background to fit the full area of the element, if the element has an arbitrary width, depending on the users screen size.

```
#home_data_communication {background:url(../images/home/data-com-bg.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:cover; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;}
```

I can do this

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {

#home_data_communication {background-image:url../images/home/data-com-bg@2x.jpg);}
```

But I dont know what the background size will be. Is there some CSS trick here? How do I have full size backgrounds with retina quality background images?

Comment: Try `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already be using background-size: cover; and media queries so I am not quite sure where the issue is. background-size: cover; uses some css magic to alter the size of the image so that it always fits the screen regardless of how large the screen gets. This can cause the image to get blown out of proportion as the screen gets bigger or cause the image to get too tiny on small screens. You may consider using css breakpoints where you will switch to a different version of the image that may fit better as certain sizes.

```
body {
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("/img/image-xs.png");
    }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("/img/image-sm.png");
    }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("/img/image-md.png");
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("/img/image-lg.png");
    }
}
```

That snippet uses bootstraps standard breakpoints as well as a custom image for each potential size. You may not be using bootstrap, but it is shown as a proof of concept. The snippet was taken in part from https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries